# Javascript factorial function stack overflow

Tags: javascript

Why does the following javascript factorial function throw a stack overflow error when called?

```
function fact(n) {
    return function () {
        var n = n;
        return (n < 2) ? 1 : (n*fact(n - 1));
    }();
};
```

When I remove the line `var n = n;` it works as expected. Also, I'm aware that the inner function is redundant, it's just there to trigger the error.

Answer (score 8):

`var n = n` *in that situation* effectively does `n = undefined` because the formal parameter `n` and the declared `n` are from different scopes. In your comment declaration `n` and formal parameter `n` are in same scope so it's not the same situation.

`undefined < 2` is always false, so it keeps calling `fact` forever.

Comment: Thanks! I still don't quite get it. If I do `var f = function(a) {var a = a; console.log(a);}` and call `f(3)` the number `3` is printed to the console.

Comment: @Jonas that's completely different from your code though. Your code is like: `var f = function(a) {return function(){var a = a; console.log(a);}();}`

Comment: Thanks again @Esailija. This is still a mystery to me. I don't understand why `n` has to be in **the same scope** in order for `var n = n` to work as expected. A pointer to some resource on how scopes work in JS would be much apprieciated.

Answer (score 1):

`var n = n` <- two problems here.

1: You have two variable with the same name, how could they be differenciated

2: `var n = n` is equal to `var n = undefined`, witch result in `false` `return` and loop forever

What you want to do is :

```
function fact(n1) {
    return function (n1) {
        var n = n1;
        return (n < 2) ? 1 : (n*fact(n - 1));
    }();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `var n = n;` isn't necessary, because it's defining a '*new*' variable called `n`, and setting it to `n`.

Your function is returning the **result** from an anonymous function, which *isn't* necessary.

The parameter `n` is in the main function, *not* the anonymous function.

*I also spaced the `*` symbol, in `(n*fact(n - 1))`*

- The original code:

  ```
  function fact(n) {
      return function () {
          var n = n;
          return (n < 2) ? 1 : (n*fact(n - 1));
      }();
  };
  ```
- The updated code:

  ```
  function fact(n) {
      return (n < 2) ? 1 : (n * fact(n - 1));
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

@[Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) already explained the cause. Try:

```
function fact(n) {
  return function(n) {return n && n > 1 && n*(fact(n-1)) || 1;}(n);
  //                                                            ^ pass n here
};
```

Or use the closure:

```
function fact(n) {
  return function() {return n && n > 1 && n*(fact(n-1)) || 1;}();
};
```

Or indeed just use:

```
function fact(n) {
  return n && n > 1 && n*(fact(n-1)) || 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to omit the re-declaration of `var n` and the code is working fine. But i would go for a `for` loop in this one, it makes half the time.

```js
function fact(n) {
    return function () {
        return (n < 2) ? 1 : (n*fact(n - 1));
    }();
};
let startDate = performance.now();
console.log(fact(170),`fact(170) took: ${(performance.now()-startDate)} milliseconds`);

function fact2(n) {
  let result = 1;
  for(let i = 2; i <=n; i++) {
    result *= i;
  }
  return result;
}
startDate = performance.now();
console.log(fact2(170),`fact2(170) took: ${(performance.now()-startDate)} milliseconds`);
```

PS: the timing was made out of curiosity. I wanted to see a difference between the timed needed in this answer on a *somehow* relative [answer](https://qr.ae/pNuRhC) that involved `Julia` programming language.